# Сокрытие кода

Tags: html, вёрстка

Просматриваю, значит исходный код некоторого сайта, а там в середине страницы три пустого текста. Скрытый код? Как это сделано?

Comment: скорее всего это шаблон с переносами строк, некоторые блоки не выводятся, а переносы остаются. бывает.

Comment: Э не - пустого текста строк наверное 300. И в начале ПУСТОТЫ я заметил <!-- security code-->
А в конце пустоты <!-- :) -->
Значит спрятали все-таки. Но как?

Comment: Почему бы не привести тут ссылку на загадочную страницу?

Comment: Это шутка, смайлик какбэ намекает. btw, вопрос должен быть не "как" а "что" спрятали. Откройте исходный код этой страницы (хэшкод), тоже заметите и комментарии (не такие правда) и пустые строки (и не 300 правда).  

Насчет "все спрятано" - посмотрите на динамические страницы, в которых вообще разметки нету, все генерится в скриптах. Например страницы ExtJs... [клуц](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext-4.1.1a-gpl/examples/kitchensink/index.html).  

Это хинт такой - все что получает браузер, отображает, выдумать страницу он не может и кэш свой тоже никому трогать не разрешает...

Comment: еле откопал ссылку. На сайте даже заблокировали правую кнопку мыши и кнопки навигации по истории. 
http://www.doctorvlad.com/money/index.php/2010/05/chto-takoe-server-provajder-xosting/

Comment: Нет, навигация работает

Answer (score 2):

Просто пустые строки. На испуг берут пионэров : )
[image]

Comment: Согласен. Из той же оперы, как и `I_LOVE_YOU.jpg (1000 пробелов).ехе`

Answer (score 0):

Снифером посмотрите что передается браузеру, хотя сомневаюсь что скрытый код.

Comment: Посмотрел код страницы снифером, ничего не грузится просто пустота, развелкалово для кулхацкеров не более не менее.

Comment: Да, я пока курил, так и догадался. Влепили пустых строк и смайл - вот вам! ))